# Programmatically access files in a device showing up in 'This PC'

Tags: r, windows, prompt, drive, clsid

I am on Windows 10. I want to write a function (in `R`) to copy the files stored in a camera (actually in the SD of the camera, but I cannot just read the memory card in the PC), to a different storage unit (say, the pc or an external HDD).

The camera is connected to the PC via an USB cable.

The problem I am facing is that, when opening the File Explorer, the camera is showing up as a link under "This PC" with no letter to indicate the drive (e.g., 'G:/').

While I can see the files using the file explorer window, I cannot find a way to get to those file from a cli type of interface (e.g., the command prompt, or the R console).

Googling, I found that 'This PC' is not a folder but rather a link to something in the registry called CLSID for which the identifier should be `{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}`. However this is very confusing to me and I cannot figure out how to use this information.

Is there a way to do it? And if so: how?

Please consider I do not know much of commands from prompt (way better off in R).

Answer (score 0):

A CLSID is just a GUID. My computer is a implementation of `IShellFolder`.

My Computer is part of the shell namespace. Several entries in the shell namespace are virtual (Control panel, scheduled tasks etc.) and cannot be accessed with low-level file functions nor cmd.exe.

While it would be possible to develop a tool that does something like `shellcopy Computer\MyCamera\*.jpg x:\backup`, I'm not aware of any existing tools that do this. You might have to code it yourself.

In the old days you would call `SHGetDesktopFolder` to get the root and then use the returned `IShellFolder` to navigate but these days it is simpler to use `IShellItem` instead.

To do this it is crucial to understand how `IShellFolder` and PIDLs work. See [Introduction to the Shell Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro) for more information...